# OpenDJ: ldapsearch filter for objectClasses returns results on only 1 of 2 replicated servers

Tags: ldap, opendj, opends

When performing the ldapsearch below with filters for users with objectClasses "CSMailForwardingPerson" and "CSContactForwardedPerson" to look for  the attribute "mailForwardingAddress" only one of my replicated servers return the expected output. Below I've shown the filtered ldapsearches, a simple ldapsearch of the user's entry to show the "mailForwardingAddress:" attribute, and the replication status. What could be causing this discrepancy? Nothing stands out in the log files.

## You'll see the discrepancy from the output of each command directly below:

```
$ ldapsearch -h ldap-1 -LLL -x '(&(objectClass=CSMailForwardingPerson)(objectClass=CSContactForwardedPerson)(!(objectClass=inetLocalMailRecipient))(mail=<person>university.edu))' mailForwardingAddress
dn: cn=<person>,ou=People,dc=cs,dc=university,dc=edu
mailForwardingAddress: person.university@gmail.com

$ ldapsearch -h ldap-2 -LLL -x '(&(objectClass=CSMailForwardingPerson)(objectClass=CSContactForwardedPerson)(!(objectClass=inetLocalMailRecipient))(mail=<person>@university.edu))' mailForwardingAddress
```

## Simple ldapsearch results:

```
$ ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap-1 cn=<person>
dn: cn=<person>,ou=People,dc=cs,dc=university,dc=edu
objectClass: CSContactForwardedPerson
objectClass: CSMailForwardingPerson
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
mail: <person>@university.edu
o: University
ou: University Dept.
givenName: <person>
mailForwardingAddress: <person>.university@gmail.com
displayName: <firstName> <lastName>
sn: <lastName>
cn: <person>

$ ldapsearch -LLL -x -h ldap-2 cn=<person>
dn: cn=<person>,ou=People,dc=cs,dc=university,dc=edu
objectClass: CSContactForwardedPerson
objectClass: CSMailForwardingPerson
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
mail: <person>@university.edu
o: University
ou: University Dept.
givenName: <person>
mailForwardingAddress: <person>.university@gmail.com
displayName: <firstName> <lastName>
sn: <lastName>
cn: <person>
```

## /opt/opendj/bin/dsreplication status

```
Suffix DN                 : Server                       : Entries : Replication enabled : DS ID : RS ID : RS Port (1) : M.C. (2) : A.O.M.C. (3) : Security (4)
--------------------------:------------------------------:---------:---------------------:-------:-------:-------------:----------:--------------:-------------
dc=cs,dc=university,dc=edu : ldap-1.university.edu:4444 : 1792    : true                : 32046 : 10474 : 8989        : 0        :              : true
dc=cs,dc=university,dc=edu : ldap-2.university.edu:4444 : 1792    : true                : 8521  : 8751  : 8989        : 0        :              : true
```

Comment: You should look into the servers’ access and errors logs to see the difference in processing on both servers. It could be tied to access controls or lack of indexes on the second server.